# PHP to execute a Ruby script and capture the JSON result

Tags: php, json

I have to work with a Ruby script that is dependent on a Gem. When the script is executed a JSON object is returned.

I am successfully executing the script using the following code.

```
<?php

$ruby = 'ruby ruby/teams.rb';

$res = system($ruby);

var_dump(json_decode($res, true));
```

The following is an example response from `ruby/teams.rb`

```
{"status"=>"active", "teamId"=>"XPLFKS59PK" }
```

My problem is that this printed directly to the screen and is not capture in the variable `$res`. When using `var_dump(json_decode($res, true))` I get `null`.

What I would like to be able to do is capture the JSON response in the `$res` variable so I can convert to an array and worth with the data.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: You should use `exec` instead of `system`. `system` returns only the last line of the executed command which in your case might be empty. Use `exec` and get all the output in an array.

Comment: Also realised I am not being returned a json array but a Ruby hash! Quick `.to_json` on the Ruby side sorted that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that this printed directly to the screen and is not capture in the variable $res.

Most likely it sends its output to `stderr` instead `stdout`, so you need to redirect the streams yourself like this:

```
$ruby = 'ruby ruby/teams.rb 2>&1';
```

Here more about stream redirection: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Or, use `exec()` instead of `system()`

Answer (score 0):

`system` only returns the last line of the commands output. In your case, i would use `exec`. Your code would look something like below

```
$ruby = 'ruby ruby/teams.rb';
exec($ruby, $res);
var_dump(json_decode(implode("", $res), true));
```